# How can we validate several group boxes that inside it radio is check or not?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have several group boxes on win form and each group box have atleast to radio buttons. I am trying to do that from given 5 group boxes user select one radio button from underlying group. If user wants to change the selection then previous selection should be dismissed.

I am using the following code to check that whether the radio button is selected or not?

```
 var allRadios = AccountgroupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();
            bool anyChecked = allRadios.Any(rb => rb.Checked);
            if (anyChecked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select any from groupbox . . .  ..  .. ");
                result = false;
            }
```

if i use the above code to check that whether the radio button is selected or not than another problem will arise. If I made selection on first group box radio button than others will pass error, because i have to give the name of group box as given in the code 'Accountgroupbox'.

[image: the group boxes on winform]

Please give some suggestions......

Comment: Any body here to answer my question?????????

Comment: you want to validate all the `radioButton` with all that `GroupBox`?

Comment: yes i want exactly this.

Comment: it seems that your code is correct to validate the `radioButton` by `groupBox` so what is the error?